# Download Older Version of SonarQube Java Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

I can see the list of older versions of the SonarQube Java plugin on this page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin by clicking on the "More versions" link. However, you can only view the release notes and not download previous versions.

Is there a place I can download them, specifically v. 4.2?

Comment: Not your question but why do you want to download a previous version ?

Comment: Because I just want an Eclipse plugin to work with the not-latest version of SonarQube. So I need a not-latest version of the plugin or SonarQube fails to start.

Comment: Which version of SQ are you trying to run ? 4.2 and 4.2.1 are both compatible with the same version of SonarQube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little URL editing reveals the full list: https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-java-plugin/